# In App Purchase not working on Xcode 5, iOS 7 simulator

Tags: ios7, xcode5, in-app-purchase

It appears that In App Purchase on the simulator has again been broken.  We are able to successfully submit an SKProduct, but we NEVER get the appropriate callback.

Any insight from others would be great...

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:skPayment];
```

No response from the observer delegate callback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the release notes for Xcode 5.0:

> StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051

The simulator documentation doesn't list storekit as being one of the API's that is not available so maybe it is temporary?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW15

Comment: Good catch with the release notes.  I do think it is temporary, it hasn't been the case with previous simulators.  At least it is a known issue.

Comment: I just heard from Apple:
"IAP is not supported in the simulator."

Thanks for that... I asked follow ups about future support and why it was dropped...

Comment: Hehe. Interested to see what responses you get to your follow ups!

Answer (score 2):

Well its working for iOS 6 but not iOS 7. Xcode 5 supports in App purchases for iOS 6 only. 
Have a happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's not the desidered behavior of the question, you can still test IAP from Simulator & Xcode5 if you  deploy and run/test for iOS6 (with test user, sandbox environment, etc...).

For me, this solution is better than deploy on device in early staging of developing phase.

Mick.